# JQuery: Image Path is different in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, image

My Problem:
I have some Images in the div (ImageRoller)

In the variable "CurrentImage" i have saved a path to one of the image

By the function "ShowNextImage" i want to have the image path of the next image: ("Images/Frangipani Flowers.jpg")

It works in FF and all normal Browsers, but not in IE.

IE searches in this part (img[src='" +CurrentImage+ "']) not like all other browser for **Images/Forest Flowers.jpg** but rather a path like **file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/jquery%20learning/Images/Autumn%20Leaves.jpg**

How can I change this in IE to the short image path (**Images/Forest Flowers.jpg**), or is this even impossible?

Here the code:

```
<div class="ImageRoller">
  <img src="**Images/Forest Flowers.jpg**" />
  <img src="Images/Frangipani Flowers.jpg" />
  <img src="Images/Garden.jpg" />
  <img src="Images/Green Sea Turtle.jpg" />
</div>

    function ShowNextImage()
    {
    var CurrentImage = "Images/Forest Flowers.jpg";
    var ImagePathOfTheNextImage = $(".ImageRoller img[src='" +CurrentImage+ "']").next("img").attr("src");

    ShowImage(ImagePathOfTheNextImage);     
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error in IE? Or you just do not want the absolute path of the img src to be displayed?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply
It doesn't work in IE becauce there is the long path.
I want to search the image with the value from var CurrentImage. But there is no path like this in my images becauce IE generates this long path.

Comment: Why not use the data() function to store the current image (element) in the ImageRoller element? Means you don't have to do a select by image path at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function ShowNextImage()
{
    var CurrentImage = "Images/Forest Flowers.jpg";
    if( $.browser.msie ) {
        var loc = document.location.href;   
        CurrentImage = loc.substring( 0, loc.lastIndexOf( '/' ) ) + CurrentImage;
    }
    var ImagePathOfTheNextImage = $(".ImageRoller img[src='" +CurrentImage+ "']").next("img").attr("src");

    showImage( ImagePathOfTheNextImage );
}
```

Comment: This generates only the whole path of the image

I think the problem is in this area (.ImageRoller img[src='" +CurrentImage+ "'])

this part searches the image with exact this path of "CurrentImage", but in IE there is no Image like this becauce it builds a the long image path